# Django: How do I access post data and match with a criteria

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need some guidance on best practice implementation of the following.

I have a scenario where I am building an app, but if it matches a certain "category" or "locale" and want to redirect it to a page in between else just go the normal route.

Here is my simple views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
    ...
    kwargs = {'project_id':project_id, 'categories':request.POST['categories'], 'locale':request.POST['locale']}
    process_se(request, **kwargs)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.next_url)
```

Here is what I have in my models.py file but it seems to be very inconsistent.
Is there a better way to handle this request?

```
def process_se(self, request, **kwargs):
    if "All" or "Sweden" in kwargs['locale']:
        if "Technology" or "Internet" in kwargs['categories']:    
            next_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('project_new_se', kwargs={'project_id': self.id}))
    else:
        next_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('project_new_step2', kwargs={'project_id': self.id}))
    self.next_url = next_url
```

UPDATES:

I am using `forms.ModelForm`, `categories` and `locales` are `ManyToManyField`'s
I have simulated a for in the shell and still seem to get no result

Here is the cleaned_data output

```
f.cleaned_data
{'locale': [<Locale: Sweden>, <Locale: All>], 'categories': [<Category: Technology>, <Category: Internet>]}
```

Although running this for fields in the form seem to render perfectly fine based on your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally proposed putting this code in the form class, but ApPeL revised the question to point out that `locale` and `categories` are many-to-many fields on the model. So now I suggest putting a method like this in your model:

```
def requires_swedish_setup(self):
    """
    Return True if this project requires extra Swedish setup.
    """
    return (self.locale.filter(name__in = ('All', 'Sweden')).exists())
            and self.categories.filter(name__in = ('Technology', 'Internet')).exists())
```

and then implementing your view like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    project = form.save()
    next = 'project_new_step2'
    if project.requires_swedish_setup():
        next = 'project_new_se'
    next_url = reverse(next, kwargs={'project_id': project.id})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
```

Some notes:

- I'm assuming that `Locale` and `Category` objects have `name` fields (if not, use whatever field contains the name you are testing).
- It's not a good idea to read form data out of `request.POST` (widgets haven't had a chance to run, and it hasn't been validated): it's better to use `form.cleaned_data`.
- You don't need to call `request.build_absolute_uri` in this case: it's fine to feed the result of `reverse` directly to `HttpResponseRedirect`.
- `"All" or "Sweden" in kwargs['locale']` is probably not what you mean: it parses like `"All" or ("Sweden" in kwargs['locale'])` and so is always true.

Comment: @garteh thank you so much for this detailed description, although it still seems to fail along the way, and this might be due to the fact that I am using ManyToManyFields - I added some extra updates above, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I see: locale and categories are objects. So you can't compare them directly with strings, you have to compare their *names* with strings. See my update.

Comment: Legen -- WAIT FOR IT -- dary! Worked like a charm, edited a little bit, you need to have .all() in the manytomany fields otherwise it'll raise an error and also needed to pass the project object in the view :)

Comment: On further reflection, I think it's best to ask the database to do the searching for you. See my revision.